# The problem with creating a selector to search for the attribute in the class name - Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, css-selectors

I have four elements on the page and these elements are changed (exactly their color) when the user types in the correct or incorrect string (new password - lowercase, uppercase ... validation). When the user types the correct string, the word "active" is added to the class name of each item at the end. I want to find an element without "active" at the end. But I can't create the right selector.

[image]

This selector works well and finds the fourth element

```
"//*[@id='PasswordList']/li[4]"
```

But when I try to modify it, it stops working

```
//*(@id='PasswordList'/li[4]) and [not(*contains(@class, 'li-one-number active'))]
```

Comment: How and why do you _try to modify it_?

Comment: I'm trying to change this selector because I need to find the one element that doesn't have "active" at the end